# Error detection and correction

Tags: hamming-code

My message bit is `10011010`, so code word for this is `0110` and now the codeword is `011100101010`.

Suppose the error is in 10th bits and it becomes `011100101110`, so finding parity bits:

```
p1=1+3+5+7+9+11=010111=even number of 1 therefore=0
p2=2+3+6+7+10+11=110111=1
p4=4+5+6+7=1001=0
p8=8+9+10+11+12=01110=1
```

Comparing with the message the parity is false for 4 and 8 position ie 4+8=12, but in fact we have made errors in 10 bit. Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

It works a little bit different. When you check parity, you don't use parity bits to count it (you count them now). So:

```
p1 = 3+5+7+9+11 = 10111 = 0 (OK)
p2 = 3+6+7+10+11 = 10111 = 0 (WRONG)
p4 = 5+6+7 = 010 = 1 (OK)
p8 = 9+10+11+12 = 1110 = 1 (WRONG)
```

So `2+8 = 10`.